# Uninitialized values behave as expected on Linux but not Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++

Why do uninitialized "max" and "min" values work on Linux but not Windows? For example:

```
double max, min, test;
while (1)
{
  std::cin >> test;
  if (test > max)
    max = test;

  if (test < min)
    min = test;
}
```

This works on Linux. I know for a fact because I've been using this (although I didn't realize until now how terrible this is) for at least 3 months now. However, I've been told by a number of co-workers that this is broken on their machines: They compile using Visual Studio. Is there some validity to their statements, and why? Is this simply a case of UB? If so, how has it been working for the past months without me noticing?

Also note: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Define "broken". Does it compile?

Comment: Clarify "works" and "broken".  What exactly is not working?

Comment: Works is when it performs as expected: gives the max and min values entered. Broken is when it gives really odd values as the max and min.

Comment: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html

Comment: @Mehrdad I got the point, thanks... To quote myself: *Is this simply a case of UB?* I knew it was possible that it was UB, but I wasn't sure, and wanted to verify that my suspicions were, in fact, correct.

Comment: @Drise: It definitely was :) you were reading from `max` before writing to it!

Comment: There are some cases in C++11 where zero initialization is supposed to be done that Visual Studio does not do yet. Also compilers sometimes do zero initialization when it's not required in some mode. For example debug modes often do extra zero initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, your code will appear to work if the uninitialized variables `min` and `max` just so happen to hold values that compare in between the actual minimum and maximum values encountered in `test`. The object representation of an uninitialized automatic variable may or may not be consistent, depending on compiler, options, and the code in the rest of the program. Reading an uninitialized value is certainly UB. UB may or may not be consistent.

So for example, one simple way that you could get the behavior you observe is if:

- your test sets all include both positive and negative values,
- gcc/linux consistently puts an all-bits-zero representation in the uninitialized variables,
- VS consistently puts a NaN in the uninitialized variables (so `test < min` and `test > max` are both always false).

Depending on what your test data is, and what "broken on their machines" means, the details may be different. I've just described one possibility out of the infinite scope of UB.

Comment: My co-workers report that they are simply uninitialized when they go through the debugger. However, I am looking at them right now, and they seem 0-initialized (on linux), even though I've done nothing to make them so. These double values are member variables to a class. Is this some POD rule that I don't know of, or is it still simply UB?

Comment: @Drise: "simply uninitialized" doesn't mean much. You haven't shown your real code, so I cannot remark on that, but in the code you have shown, the variables are uninitialized. There are some bytes at the memory location corresponding to those variables, and those bytes have values. Even if those values are 0 on your machine, the variable is still uninitialized, so it is still UB. As it happens, the Linux kernel clears memory before assigning it to a process, so early on in the running of a program, newly-allocated memory tends to be full of zeroes.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much more sense. Thank you for finding that.

Comment: The variables would have an indeterminate value, and using an indeterminate value _may_ result in undefined behavior. However, the actual values may happen to be valid and usable, and in that case using them does not result in UB. Of course I don't believe there's any standard way to determine beforehand whether this is the case or not, so practically speaking you might as well treat using indeterminate values as UB. Unless you don't need that much portability and you know that there's no possibility of UB from using indeterminate values on your platform.

Comment: Here's one reason you might want to use indeterminate values: http://research.swtch.com/sparse

Comment: +1 For explaining UB without starting a pedantic rant about it.

Comment: @barnes53: 4.1/1: "A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue ... if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has undeﬁned behavior." Indeterminate values don't enter into it. It is UB to read an object that has not been initialized, even if implementation details suggest that every bit pattern represents a meaningful value.

Comment: Implementations can optimize around this restriction, and break your code, although in practice probably don't for arrays used as in your link. Implementations can also deliberately detect that it has happened and do something bizarre, which is why "This would drive valgrind nuts". Valgrind is conforming to the standard even if it aborts the program immediately, and code that relies on the implementation not to "go nuts" is not portable C++. Your link just relies on the fact that within the bounds of UB is, "behave as though the object has a value", and many implementations do that.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: sorry, apparently I just delayed the pedantic rant until the comments ;-)

Comment: "if the object is uninitialized..." If the object has been default initialized then I do not think it counts as uninitialized, even for types where default initialization is 'no initialization is performed' and the object is specified to have indeterminate value. I believe that statement will only apply to accessing objects in a context such that initialization is not performed at all. Otherwise is there a point in specifying that objects have indeterminate value?

Comment: Additionally I want to agree that the fact that every bit pattern represents a meaningful value for some implementation is not necessarily enough to avoid UB when accessing an object of indeterminate value. Since the spec only says that accessing an indeterminate value 'may' have UB, it's up to an implementation to define when indeterminate value can be safely read. So this is just another case where whether or not a C++ program has undefined behavior under the C++ spec is dependent on an implementation's details.

Comment: @bames53: well, the standard doesn't actually define "uninitialized", so we're left trying to guess what it's supposed to mean based on English. I've always assumed that if no initialization is performed, then the object is "uninitialized", but that may not be the intention of the authors. In plain English there's a flat contradiction between an object having been "initialized" (in a default way or any other way), and no initialization having been performed, so personally I'm not entirely impressed by the language in the standard.

Comment: I think it may be the result of different parts of the standard being written at different times, perhaps without proper cross-referencing, and certainly without a clear statement of the different ways in which memory can hold junk. "Not being initialized" by default initialization results in an indeterminate value, whereas "being uninitialized" results in UB on read, but I suspect that those two separate passages are *trying* to talk about the same situation, and saying subtly different things about it. There's yet more text elsewhere about things having been (or not been) constructed.

Comment: But anyway, in this case the object, whether it's uninitialized or merely not initialized, is a `double`. So if nothing else it's plausible that on some implementation somewhere it could hold a signalling NaN, such that using it does in fact trash the program. I think we can all agree that the code is bad, regardless of whether there are certain possibilities for certain implementation-defined behaviors that could result in it not being UB on certain implementations. The code you link to would fail if an indeterminate value is a trap representation of `int`, which is vastly rarer.

Comment: Well one way for something to be initialized (e.g., default initialization) but without initialization having been performed, is that no act of initialization is necessary for the object to be initialized. But certainly the specs language doesn't make it clear, and since there's no portable way to check if an indeterminate value is actually usable I would certainly agree that it's reasonable to treat objects with indeterminate value the same as uninitialized objects.

Comment: Also, one common situation with ints of indeterminate value is that in VS debug mode accessing them can pop up a dialog. This doesn't add any weight to either side of the argument, since trapping behavior isn't necessarily the only condition that the spec allows to result in undefined behavior when accessing an object of indeterminate value. UB is occurring, but whether it's because the objects are technically uninitialized or because VS implementation details are such that accessing objects of indeterminate value can do that, even without trapping representations, isn't absolutely clear.

Answer (score 8):

This "works" on no platform.

All it does is to invoke *Undefined Behavior*. *"Seems to do what I expected it to"* is but one way for *UB* to materialize itself. It's a rather unfortunate one, though, because it makes you believe your code is fine, until one day it explodes into your customer's face.

Answer (score 6):

Because undefined behaviour is undefined. It might work, or it might not work, you just don't know. Apparently, on your linux environment, it works.

Comment: @Drise: You need to understand that "undefined" does ***NOT*** mean "you will get an error" or "it depends on the details" or anything else. It *literally* means it's **undefined** (it can result in **anything** or *nothing*)... period. Repeat after me: Undefined behavior does ***NOT*** imply I will get an error; Undefined behavior does ***NOT*** imply I will get an error...

Comment: Yes. Maybe something happens in Linux that makes it work. But that's undefined, you don't know whether it will work or not.

Comment: Yes. Undefined doesn't mean it isn't consistent. It may or may not be. This is exactly the sort of thing I would expect to be undefined but consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Using the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, so anything can happen. *Anything*, which means the code may **seem** to work, it may crash, or it may cause demons to fly out of your nose.